# Is set of convergent sequence with sup norm Banach?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $(c, \|.\|_{\infty})$ be the vector space of all real convergent sequence with sup norm. Is the space complete?

I know $(l^\infty, \|.\|_{\infty})$ is a Banach space and $c$ is subset of $l^\infty$. If I can show that $c$ is closed the it becomes complete. But all this is if the $c$ is known to be complete. What do you say about it? Is it complete? If not what Cauchy sequence in $c$ can you provide which is not convergent convergent with $\sup$ norm in $c$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, $c$ is closed. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let $(x(n)_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be an element of $c$ and suppose that $\bigl(x(n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges (in $l^\infty$) to some sequence $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let $l_n$ be the limit of the sequence $x(n)$. The sequence $x(n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $l^\infty$. Therefore, $(l_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers and so it converges to some $l\in\mathbb R$. I will prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=l$, thereby proving that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in c$.

Take $\varepsilon>0$ and take $\varepsilon'\in(0,\varepsilon)$. There is some $p\in\mathbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant p\implies\bigl\|x-x(n)\bigr\|_\infty<\varepsilon'.$$Therefore, since $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}l_n$ and $l_n=\lim x(n)$,$$n\geqslant p\implies|l-l_n|\leqslant\varepsilon'<\varepsilon.$$

Since $c$ is closed in $l^\infty$ and $l^\infty$ is complete, $c$ is complete.

Comment: Maybe it's the notation that's confusing for me,  but aren't by definition $x(n)$ elements of $c$ and therefore convergent? Why do you need to suppose in your first line that the sequence $(x(n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}})$ converges?

Comment: @Spaced *Each* $x(n)$ converges, but that doesn't mean that the whole sequence $\bigl(x(n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges in $l^\infty$. Suppose, for instance, that $x(n)$ is the sequence $n+1,n+\frac12,n+\frac13,n+\frac14,\ldots$ Then each sequence $x(n)$ converges (to $n$), but the sequence $\bigl(x(n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does not converge in $l^\infty$ (for instance, it is not bounded).

Comment: thank you,  that does make sense. I believe I confuse myself with the notation. If I say $x=(x_n^1, x_n^2, x_n^3, \dots )$ is an element of $c$, then for each $k= 1, 2, \dots $ $x_n^k$ converges as $n \to \infty$ and you are considering the sequence $(x_n^k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ I believe.

Comment: @Spaced Yes, that's it.

Comment: One more question, I couldn't work out why $l_k := \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^k$ gives again a Cauchy sequence $(l_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. Indeed the limit exists because of my comment above and also we have for each fixed $k$ that $(x_n^k)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a cauchy sequence, but how does that make $(l_k)_k$ a Cauchy Sequence?

Comment: @Spaced Take $\varepsilon>0$. There is a natural $p$ such that $m,n\geqslant p\implies\|x_n-x_m\|_\infty<\varepsilon$. But then $m,n\geqslant p\implies|l_n-l_m|\leqslant\varepsilon$.

Comment: Dear @JoséCarlosSantos, I couldn't understand the "Therefore" part. You assume $l=\lim x$. But isn't that what there is to prove?

Comment: @rgm Right. What I meant was that $\lim_{n\to\infty}l_n=l$. I've edited my answer.